# Including a Twig template in a JQuery .html() call and remove new lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony, twig

I want to create a dialog box that will be the content of another Twig file. So in the JQuery call, I have:

```
$('<div></div>')
    .html('{% include "folder/file.html.twig" %}')
    .dialog({....
```

In file.html.twig there are new lines, so when placed into the .html call it fails as the .html call doesn't allow for new lines. If there was a way to use the replace from Twig to get rid of all new lines that may work, however, when I use:

```
$('<div></div>')
    .html('{% include "folder/file.html.twig"|replace({"\n":""}) %}')
    .dialog({....
```

it replaces any new lines (that don't exist) out of the path, not the rendered content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the spaceless tag. It gets rid of all whitespace, so your code and content will not be affected, but it will all display in one line:

```
$('<div></div>')
    .html('{% spaceless %}{% include "folder/file.html.twig" %}{% endspaceless %}')
    .dialog({....
```

See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/spaceless.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a filter using the [`filter` tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/filter.html), instead of a pipe.

```
$('<div></div>')
    .html('{% filter replace({"\n":""})%}{% include "folder/file.html.twig" %}{% endfilter}')
    .dialog({....
```

---

However instead of the replace, use the [`json_encode` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html) to turn the HTML into a string, rather than just placing it between quotes. This will also prevent problems when the included HTML contains quotes.

```
$('<div></div>')
    .html({% filter json_encode %}{% include "folder/file.html.twig" %}{% endfilter %})
    .dialog({....
```

Comment: This gets the code into the html tag, but unfortunately it doesn't render the html then. I have a form as part of the html so the form code shows instead. Is there a way just to run this filter on new lines or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try the backtick (`) delimiter

```
$('<div></div>')
.html(`{% include "folder/file.html.twig" %}`)
.dialog({....
```

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: That did the trick in some more recent browsers, however, on that page if you go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility you can see no IE has comparability, so while this will be an (much needed) option down the track, unfortunately at the moment we need to support IE, mobile browsers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this certainly exemplifies the problems of mixing twig html output within JavaScript, this very easily gets very messy, very quickly - speaking from experience.

Nonetheless, you can hack around this by exposing the included template as a rendered controller, this way you can prepare the response->getContent() with more ease in pure PHP i.e

{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Folder:file')) }}

```
....
Class Folder{
    ....
    public function fileAction(){
        ....
        $included_template_content = $this->renderView("folder/file.html.twig");
        // Process Content for javascript using php functions
        return new Response($included_template_content);
    }
    ....
}
....
```

alternatively, if you want to avoid the extra sub-request you can explore doing this in a Twig Extension

Answer (score 0):

You can user ajax for do this be like :

```
public function yourAction(Request $request)
{
    $template =  $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ? 'template_xhr.html.twig' : 'template.html.twig';

    return $this->render($template);
}
```

and ajax :

```
$.ajax({ url : 'url', success : function(data) { 
          $("#texte").html(data)
   })
```